# Unexpected end of input on ember .save(), empty responseText

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, responsetext, http-put

I'm doing a PUT request with ember .save() method. Returned status is 200, but I keep getting the "unexpected end of input error". I think it might be because request is returning and empty json responseText as shown here :

http://gyazo.com/6cbb68c1de8fd79a6ec90e6f122dc132

Do you have any ideas how I can solve this problem or the exact reason I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `RESTAdapter` sets the jQuery `$.ajax` option `dataType` to `json`. This causes all responses to be treated as JSON and parsed.

I believe your getting that error because the response is not valid JSON.

There are two ways to fix this:

### 1. Change the Server Response

Change the server to it returns a valid JSON string and it will stop you getting that error.

### 2. Implement a Custom Ember Data Adapter

You can implement a custom adapter that sets the `dataType` option to `text` when you call .save()`

```
App.MyAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  // By default, the RESTAdapter sets 'dataType'
  // to JSON - causing the response text to be
  // treated as a JSON resulting in an error
  // for responses that are not valid JSON.

  // We want to override this if we are not
  // expecting JSON from the server

  ajaxOptions: function(url, type, options) {
    // get the default RESTAdapter 'ajaxOptions'
    var hash = this._super(url, type, options);

    // override if it's a PUT request
    if (type === 'PUT') {
      hash.dataType = 'text';
    }
    return hash;
  },

  ajaxSuccess: function(jqXHR, data) {
    if (typeof data === 'string') {
      // return an empty object so the Serializer
      // handles it correctly
      return {};
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

I've created a JSBin that demonstrates this. When you click the save button the mocked ajax response returns the same string (' ' - looks like one space character?) that your server is returning.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/durugo/5/edit?js,output

Comment: Could you link me to an example of how to modify the adapter for this or just give me a short example? I'm still fairly new to ember.